Conditional element is not rendering before return "redirect:/"
enter image description here
If I remove the line return "redirect:/login"; then the conditional element will appear.
If I remain the line return "redirect:/login"; then the conditional element will not appear and then the page will redirect to login page.
What is that I cannot understand, please help. Thank you.
Java code:
@PostMapping
public String signup(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) throws InterruptedException {
    String error = null;

    if (!userService.isUsernameAvailable(user.getUsername())) {
        error = USERNAME_EXISTS;
    }

    if (error == null && userService.createUser(user) < 0) {
        error = SIGNUP_COMMON_ERROR;
    }

    if (error != null) {
        model.addAttribute("signupError", error);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("signupSuccess", true); 
        return "redirect:/login"; <-------------------
    }

    return "signup";
}

Thymeleaf:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">

    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-black">
    <div class="container justify-content-center w-50 p-3" style="background-color: #eeeeee; margin-top: 5em;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><a id="back-to-login" th:href="@{/login}">Back to Login</a></label>
        </div>
        <h1 class="display-5">Sign Up</h1>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/signup}" method="POST">



            <div id="success-msg" th:if="${signupSuccess}" class="alert alert-dark">
                You successfully signed up! Please continue to the <a th:href="@{/login}">login</a> page.
            </div>



            <div th:if="${signupError}" class="alert alert-danger">
                <span th:text="${signupError}">Example Signup Error Message</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="input" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="20" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="input" name="lastName" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="20" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>
                    <input type="input" name="username" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Enter Username" maxlength="20" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Enter Password" maxlength="20" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="signup-button">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>


Model attributes do not survive redirects. Add RedirectAttributes redirAttr to the signup method signature and add your signupSuccess attribute via redirAttr.addFlashAttribute() or redirAttr.addAttribute(). Here is an example that works:
@Controller
public class TestController {
  @GetMapping("/getForRedirect")
  public String getForRedirect(RedirectAttributes redirAttr) {
    redirAttr.addFlashAttribute("name", "joe");
    return "redirect:/redirected";
  }

  @GetMapping("/redirected")
  public String redirected(Model model) {
    return "redirected";
  }
}


I try both but none works

I have updated my answer with a trivial example that works. 'joe' is presented on the redirected.html page.
